# Vue for input.length change background color

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Code consists of two input field , if the value of the `Fullname` is greater than 3, then its suppose to change the `initial` input field background into green. Is there a way to do that ?

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="fullname" placeholder="Enter Full Name" @input="changeInitialColor"/>
  <input type="text" v-model="initial" placeholder="On Full Name make it green"/>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    fullname:'',
    inital:''
  },
  methods: {
    changeInitialColor(){
     if(this.fullname.length > 3){
      console.log('Change v-model=Initial field color into green');
     }
     else{
      console.log("Dont change color");
     }
    }
  }
})
```

Below is the code on `JSFIDDLE`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/kya27g9w/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be to use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)  with [css class bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

```
<input type="text" v-model="fullname" placeholder="Enter Full Name"/>
<input type="text" v-model="initial" :class="{ green: fullnameIsMoreThan3Chars }"/>

// --
,methods: { ... }
,computed: {
    fullnameIsMoreThan3Chars(){
        return this.fullname.length > 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use style or class binding like :

`style="{'background-color':fullname.length>3?'green':''}"`:

```
 <input type="text" v-model="initial"
 style="{'background-color':fullname.length>3?'green':''}" 
placeholder="On Full Name make it green"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to conditionally add a class to initial based on the length of the fullname input.

```
<input type="text" v-model="initial" placeholder="On Full Name makes it green" :class="{'green': fullname.length > 3}"/>
```

You can also create a computed property to know if the fullname input is greater than three and use that computed value instead (should keep your template cleaner)

```
<input type="text" v-model="initial" placeholder="On Full Name makes it green" :class="{'green': fullNameOk}"/>

{
  ...
  computed: {
    fullNameOk() {
      return this.fullname.length > 3
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaireina/g9s2z3e6/5/)